# How to make SVG map responsive to the width of its parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive-design

I have SVG map and it is placed within the **.container**

The problem is I cannot set the width of the SVG to be always 100% of the width of the **.container** element.

So if I set:

```
    .container {
      width: 500px;
    }
```

The SVG map is cropped and part of it isn't visible.

**Desired result:**

I want it to behave like in this example: 
https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=austria

**1.** When I zoom in or drag out the map it's ok if it's cropped.

**2.** When I change the viewport (for example by resizing the browser window) it should be responsive to the width of its parent element.

Here is the snippet with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/marektchas/epxtuwvo/

One more note - if I use viewbox (in any configuration) the entire construction is broken.

Comment: Give your svg element a `viewBox`, for example `viewBox= "0 0 620 315"`.  Also remove the width and the height for the svg element. This way the svg will take the width of the `.main-container`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question - if I use viewbox it breaks it - the zoom functionality stops to work properly and it makes the entire construction useless.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Does perhaps any of these solutions work for you (scroll down) https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ (padding bottom hacks maybe)

Comment: I think the problem here is the JS code regarding the zooming

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/pan-and-zoom/

Comment: Any ideas what is wrong with my JS code and how to resolve that conflict between viewbox and zooming?